# Cakephp internal server error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting Internal Server Error when I switched over App folder with a new App folder from another server. I have reconfigured the database credentials but it's still not working.

Do you have any idea what this is for?

The site is ldr.com.au

Below is what I have in .htaccess of app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to help without more information. Check your server logs, a 500 error usually means something is wrong with the configuration - file permissions, `.htaccess` ~

Comment: Check your .htaccess. PS. linking to a site with a 500 error is pretty useless, there won't be any information on why the error happens

Comment: check your .htaccess, always first place to go for 500 errors

Comment: what do you normally do when you want to transfer a new app folder to the server? Is there something that you need to watch out for?

Comment: Check about your tmp folder ...

Comment: You need to check your apache logs; it will most likely tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry. Where do you find Apache logs?

Comment: What Linux do you use? For Debian/Ubuntu it is /var/log/apache2/error.log. Do a tail -f on the file, and then visit the 500 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this for more information: 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

I'm not understanding your problem, but I think you will find your answer up there.

Comment: It was missing .htaccess file on webroot. When I added one it worked like a charm. I got this idea from you. Thank you very much!

Comment: This Link is nowt working... book.cakephp has update there site

Answer (score 2):

If you are stand on Root folder

your .htaccess should like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are stand in to app folder

your .htaccess should like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What if you have this directory structure:

html
   app
      webroot
   subdomain
      app
         webroot

What should the .htaccess files in the subdomain directory look like?